# What is the latest version of Biztalk Adapter pack?

Tags: adapter, biztalk

I need to install both x86, x64 version of Biztalk adapter pack.
What is the latest version of BAP ?

Comment: Which version of BizTalk

Comment: BizTalk Adapter Pack 2.0. Link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=2755

Comment: I am using Biztalk 2010